# Problem accessing MICROSOFT##SSEE database (Error: 18456, Severity: 14, State: 16.)

Tags: sql-server-2005, sql, login

After an unexpected server shutdown due to a power failure, I can no longer connect to the internal windows database MICROSOFT##SSEE which is hosting Central Admin for my SBS 2008 server.

The log shows:

```
  Error: 18456, Severity: 14, State: 16.
  Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE'. [CLIENT: <named pipe>]
```

I've tried to connect using the SQL Management studio (connecting to .pipemssql$microsoft##sseesqlquery) but no luck.

The SQL Server Configuration Manager doesn't show a entry for 'Protocols for MICROSOFT##SSEE' (but shows it for 2 other database hosted on the same SQL server 2005 Express edition.

I have tried to restore the master.ldf and mastlog.log files from a backup, but the issue persists.

Comment: I'm doing a little tour of questions that relate to WID on Windows 2008 to note that Windows 2012 changes the pipe to `\\.\pipe\MICROSOFT##WID\tsql\query`

Comment: A blog entry about Error: 18456 and the state codes: [Troubleshooting Error 18456](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2011/01/14/sql-server-v-next-denali-additional-states-for-error-18456.aspx) seems to suggest the default database isn't accessible.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using sqlcmd to connect to the service when it's running in single user mode?

Configure the service's startup options for '-m' and restart the service.

Then use this to connect from a command line:

```
sqlcmd -E -S \\.\pipe\MSSQL$MICROSOFT##SSEE\sql\query
```

Alternatively, this article can help you connect via SSMS in single user mode: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188236.aspx

Check and see if 'NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE' has a login to the instance with login rights.